# How to show in a UITextField the value from UIDataPicker without Buttons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, events, picker

I have an application for iPad where i want to use the UIdataPicker to display its value in a UITextField automatically without buttons.

I don't know what kind of event in the picker i need.
Also, what source i need to put to achieve it.

I would like your help, Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:nil @selector(updateUITextField) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(void)updateUITextField{
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                 [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [df release];
}
```

Dont forget to add UIPickerViewDelegate to you header file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIControlEventValueChanged control event to detect when the picker's value has been changed. In this method, pass the picker's date property to the UITextField, or optionally to a variable that the TextField reads.

Here's Apple's documentation and suggested practice for interpreting a picker's value (see *[Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)*).